# Sup and inf of a set

Tags: analysis

please haw to find the sup and the inf of the following set

$$ A=\{\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}, n\in \{1,2,3,...\}\}$$

I tried this $A=B\cup C$ where
 $B=\{\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{n}, n=2k\}$ and

$C=\{\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{n}, n=2k+1\}$

but I don't know how to continue?

Comment: The $B$ and $C$ sets are a good idea.  Can you find the $\sup$ and $\inf$ over the set $B$?

Comment: Set $a_n=\frac 1{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^n}n$, show $a_{2n}>0\ \searrow$ and $a_{2n+1}<0\ \nearrow$ from there, inf and sup are easily deduced.

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that $-\frac{1}{2}\le\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{\le \frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}\le\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{3}{4},$ ($\frac{3}{4}$ if $n\ge2$).

The first inequality became equal iff $n=1$, so the inf is $-\frac{1}{2}$.
On the other hand, the right inequality is an equal iff $n=2$, hence the $\sup$ is $\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: how you get this inequality?

Comment: The sequences are decreasing and increasing monotonically, so just look at first terms.

Comment: how to prove that $\frac{1}{2^n} +\frac{1}{n}$ is increasing? @Marco Lecci

Comment: Use induction. Or study the derivative of $f(x):=\frac{1}{2^x}+\frac{1}{x}$ with $x \in [1,+\infty)$.

Comment: I put $u_n=\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{n}$ I found that $u_{n+1}-u_n=-(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)})<0$ it is right? @Marco Lecci

Comment: Yes is correct. Do the first case of induction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you calculated some values of the sequence

$a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

What should the supremum and infimum be?
Keep in mind, that we call a supremum/infimum the maximum/minimum if it is an element of the set.

Splitting into two subsequences is a good idea.

Show that the sequences are increasing/decreasing monotonically.
Like this you can verify your guess for supremum and infimum and also show that these are maximum and minimum.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at some initial terms first .

We have $$ -1/2, 3/4,-5/{24},5/{16},-\frac {27}{160},...$$

Notice that both positive and negative terms are decreasing in magnitude so $$\sup A=3/4$$ and $$\inf A=-1/2$$

Answer (score 0):

You made a good start!

Consider $n=2k,k\ge 1$:
$$\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\frac1{2^{2k}}+\frac1{2k}\le \frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2}=\frac34, \ \text{because:} \ \frac1{2^{2k}}\le \frac1{2^2},\frac1{2k}\le \frac1{2}.$$
Now consider $n=2k+1,k\ge 0$:
$$\frac1{2^n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\frac1{2^{2k+1}}-\frac1{2k+1}\ge \frac1{2}-1=-\frac12,$$
because, the function $f(x)=\frac1{2^{2x+1}}-\frac1{2x+1},x\ge 0$ is an increasing function:
$$f'(x)=-\frac{2\ln 2}{2^{2x+1}}+\frac2{(2x+1)^2}>0 \iff \\
2^{2x+1}>\ln 2\cdot (2x+1)^2 \iff \\
2^m> m^2\ln 2,m\ge 1.$$

Comment: why $2^m> m^2 \ln(2)$ is always true? @farruhota

Comment: $\color{red}{m=1}, 2>1^2\cdot 0.69 \ \checkmark, \\ \color{red}{m=2}, 2^2>2^2\cdot 0.69 \ \checkmark, \\ \color{red}{m=3}, 2^3>3^2\cdot 0.69 \ \checkmark, \\ \color{red}{m=4}, 2^4>4^2\cdot 0.69 \ \checkmark, \\ \color{red}{m\ge 5}, 2^m>m^2>m^2\cdot \ln 2$ (last can be proved by induction).

Comment: suppose that $2^m> m^2 \ln(2)$ and we must prove it for m+1, $2^{m+1}=2^m×2> m^2 \ln(2)  \neq (m+1)^2 \ln(2)$ @farruhota

Comment: Note that $m^2>m^2\cdot \ln 2=m^2\cdot 0.69$. Now prove $2^m>m^2,m\ge 5$ by induction.

Comment: it is the same thing, $2^{m+1}=2^m×2 > 2m^2$

Comment: You need to prove:$2^m>m^2\Rightarrow 2^{m+1}>(m+1)^2$. It is: $2^{m+1}=2\cdot 2^m>2m^2>(m+1)^2 \iff (m-1)^2>2 \ \ \checkmark $

Comment: please how you write directly this $ \frac1{2^{2k+1}}-\frac1{2k+1}\ge \frac1{2}-1=-\frac12$ without using that it is increasing

Comment: When $k=0$, it is equal. When $k>0$, it is $\frac1{2^{2k+1}}-\frac1{2k+1}>-\frac12 \iff \frac1{2^{2k+1}}>\frac{1-2k}{4k+2}$, which is true, because left side is positive and right side is negative.

Comment: we don't prove it by recurrence?

Comment: because there is no need for it